# Rails Double nested form is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I am working on an application and this is an extracted part of the domain model
[image: abstract domain model]

**Customer** is a subclass of **Person** and as you can see **Address** is polymorphic: There are more models in my domainmodel that make use of this model.

These are my Model files:

model **Customer**  *file: customer.rb*

```
class Customer < Person

  has_many :homes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :homes

  validates :dateOfBirth, date: true

end
```

model **Home** *file: home.rb*

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :customer
  has_one  :address, as: :x_address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

end
```

**Address**  *file: address.rb*

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :x_address, polymorphic: true

end
```

In *customers_controller.rb* There is a method 'new' that renders a form. This form is double nested. There are fields for *Customer*, fields for *Home* and fields for *Address*.

*file: customers_controller.rb*

```
def new
    @customer = Customer.new
    home = @customer.homes.build
    home.build_address
  end
```

This method renders this form:

[image: double nested form]

And this is the code for this form

*file: _form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for @customer, :url => { :action => "newCustomer" } do |f| %>

<%= render 'errors' %>


<fieldset class="form-group">

  <div class="">
    <span class="form-control-label"> EMAIL</span>
    <span><%= f.email_field :email , :class => "form-control" %></span>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <span class="form-control-label">GESLACHT</span>
    <span><%= f.text_field :gender, :class => "form-control" %></span>
  </div>

  <div >
    <span class="form-control-label">GEBOORTEDATUM</span>
    <span class="form-control"><%= f.date_select  :dateOfBirth, :start_year => 1950  %></span>
  </div>



  <!--nesting formfields for homes and address-->

  <%= f.fields_for :homes do |home| %>
      <div class="">
        <span class="form-control-label">NAAM WONING</span>
        <span><%= home.text_field :name, :class => "form-control" %></span>
      </div>

          <%= home.fields_for :address do |adres| %>
              <div class="">
                <span class="form-control-label">STRAATNAAM</span>
                <span><%= adres.text_field :street, :class => "form-control" %></span>
              </div>
          <% end %>
  <% end %>



</fieldset>

<div class="input_row">
  <span class="input_label blank"></span>
  <span class="submit_button"><%= f.submit :value => "OPSLAAN"  %></span>
</div>
```

```
adresses schema:

 Table name: addresses

  id             :integer          not null, primary key

  street         :string
  homeNumber     :string
  postalCode     :string
  city           :string
  isPostAddress  :boolean
  x_address_id   :integer
  x_address_type :string
  created_at     :datetime         not null
  updated_at     :datetime         not null
```

And this my method for permitting all attributes in the Customers_controller:

```
    def customer_params
        params.require(:customer).permit( :email,
                                          :gender,
                                          :customerType,
                                          :dateOfBirth,
                                          :maritialStatus,
                                          :childrenCount,
                                          :partyMail,
                                          :marketingMail,
                                          homes_attributes: [:name,
                                                            addresses_attributes: [:street,
                                                                                 :homeNumber,
                                                                                 :postalCode,
                                                                                 :city,
                                                                                 :isPostaddress]])

end
```

My problem is that by submitting this form it is not creating an Address. So it does create a Customer and a Home but it seems I am doing something wrong for the address. And I dont know what. I have already searched for solutions and can't find what I am doing wrong.

Would be great if anyone has a suggestion for me

Martijn D.

Comment: Did you debug your code in controller? In create action what's in your params? Is address present in params in nested attributes?

Comment: Can you please specify the **addresses** table schema ?

Comment: Hi, added addresses table schema to post..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to formulating my problem to post it here I changed my params.require and Voila... it works now.

As the association between **Home** and **Address** is a 'has_one' this should also reflect in the params.require...

so I changed **addresses_attributes to address_atributes**

```
 def customer_params
        params.require(:customer).permit( :email,
                                          :gender,
                                          :customerType,
                                          :dateOfBirth,
                                          :maritialStatus,
                                          :childrenCount,
                                          :partyMail,
                                          :marketingMail,
                                          homes_attributes: [:name,
                                                            address_attributes: [:street,
                                                                                 :homeNumber,
                                                                                 :postalCode,
                                                                                 :city,
                                                                                 :isPostaddress]])

end
```